# Running time of recursive fibonacci series

Tags: algorithm, recursion, fibonacci

Computing the Fibonacci series is particularly slow when implemented recursively with no caching of intermediate results. What is the runtime?

Comment: Don't implement the algorithm recursively.  You can do it iteratively.  It teaches you that the implementation of algorithms matters.

Comment: Some implementations of fibonacci are slow, and some aren't. Measurements would help deduce whether yours is unreasonably slow. Source code would also allow quality commentary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is reluctant to use a search engine for such a common problem.

Comment: The recalculation isn't the fault of the recursive approach. There are recursive solutions that eliminate the recalculation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nonsense. It's possible to make a slow iterative version, and it's possible to make a fast recursive version.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework question.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: It's hard to make a slow iterative version, and hard to make a fast recursive version (depending on the language used).

Answer (score 0):

The running time of the iterative approach is O(n) where n is how many elements in your sequence.

The running time for the recursive approach is O(2^n).

```
    fib(int n){
      if(n==1 || n==2) return n;    
      else return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
    }
```

You can see how this breaks of into a tree with exponential amounts of elements.

Comment: the call stack for n = 64 would be ~2^64 levels tall before hitting a base case and solving back down the stack.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, it depends on the algorithm. If you use dynamic programming (build up the sum from the ground up using memoization), then the runtime is `O(n)` in the value of the input. (it is worth noting that this is NOT Linear time but [Pseudo-Linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) because algorithms are typically measured in the *size* of the input [number of bits in this case], not the *value* of the input).

```py
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    l = [0, 1]
    while len(l) <= n:
        l.append(l[-2] + l[-1])
    return l[-1]
```

The running time for the naive recursive approach is actually `O(φ^n)` where `φ` is the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) (approximately 1.618). That's because for every increment of 1 that you increase the input `n` by, the time to compute increases NOT by a factor of 2 as in @TylerBrown's answer, but it actually increases by a factor of about `φ` (so it is somewhat faster, but still exponentially slow).

```py
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

For example, consider how `fib(17)` takes some amount of time because it makes a tree of recursive calls. If we increment the input by 1 to have `fib(18)`, the first two calls will be `fib(17)` and `fib(16)`. Each of these calls will have to build their own tree of recursive calls.

Calling `fib(17)` AND `fib(16)` does *not* take twice as long as just calling `fib(17)` alone because the `fib(16)` tree will be a bit smaller than `fib(17)`. If the `fib(17)` tree has `x` recursive calls, then the `fib(16)` tree will have roughly `x * 0.618...` calls. Therefore,

```
number_of_calls_in_fib_18
= number_of_calls_in_fib_17 + number_of_calls_in_fib_16
≈ (x) + (x * 0.618)
= 1.618x
```